# Get error on 'gimp-image-set-active-layer' when trying to use script-fu-drop-shadow

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I would like to add a drop shadow to picture files without using the Gimp UI. I've saved this content to ~~/.config/GIMP/2.10/scripts/my.scm~:

```lisp
(define (my/add-drop-shadow filename)
  (let* ((image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)))
         (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
    ;; Apply transformations
    (script-fu-drop-shadow RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable
                            20.0 20.0 10.0 0 0.5 nil)))
```

(I know this code is not saving the image, I will add that when this works).

Unfortunately, when trying to use that, I get an error:

```
$ gimp --version
2.10.30

$ gimp -i -b '(my/add-drop-shadow "2022-11-01-080429.png")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
GIMP-Error: Calling error for procedure 'gimp-image-set-active-layer':
Procedure 'gimp-image-set-active-layer' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'active-layer'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer.

batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: Procedure execution of gimp-image-set-active-layer failed on invalid input arguments: Procedure 'gimp-image-set-active-layer' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'active-layer'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer. 

/home/cassou/.nix-profile/bin/gimp: GEGL-WARNING: (../gegl/buffer/gegl-tile-handler-cache.c:1076):gegl_tile_cache_destroy: runtime check failed: (g_queue_is_empty (&cache_queue))
EEEEeEeek! 2 GeglBuffers leaked
```

Am I doing something incorrect or is the plug-in buggy?

## Update

If I add these statements to the script at the start of the `let` body:

```
(print "=============================")
(print image)
(print drawable)
(print "=============================")
```

I get:

```
"============================="
1
2
"============================="
```

as output.

Comment: If the plugin were that buggy many "official" scripts wouldn't work. Can't see anything obvious but was is the value of `image` after the file is loaded?

Comment: @xenoid I answered by updating the original post.

Comment: Hmm where is the code that does the `gimp-image-set-active-layer`?

Comment: @xenoid I gave you all of my code and there is nothing more in the `scripts/` directory. `script-fu-drop-shadow` calls `gimp-image-set-active-layer` 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

No a script-fu expert but at least 3 problems in your call:

- The "color" argument isn't just an integer (at least in a full-RGB image), most likely a triplet, or the result of `(gimp-context-get-foreground)`
- The opacity is a `0-100` number, with `.5` you won't see much, you probably want `50` instead
- The resizing argument should be `0` or `1`

Calling from python this works:

```
pdb.script_fu_drop_shadow(image, image.active_layer,20.0, 20.0, 10.0, (0,0,0), 80, 0)
```

Comment: When I try `(script-fu-drop-shadow RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable 20.0 20.0 10.0 '(0 0 0) 50 0)`, I get `Error: <: argument 1 must be: number`.

Comment: Only two uses of `<` in the code (`drop-shadow.scm`), both as ` (< (+ shadow-offset-x shadow-transl-x) 0)` so I don't see how the result of `(+ shadow-offset-x shadow-transl-x)` couldn't be a number.